# Why scoped service disposed earlier than transient service in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net

Doc Link: [dotnet DI link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#disposal-of-services)

I have done the Tutorial step by step, but I fond a problem: Why scoped service disposed earlier than transient service in dotnet?

```
Scope 1...
ScopedDisposable.Dispose()
TransientDisposable.Dispose()

Scope 2...
ScopedDisposable.Dispose()
TransientDisposable.Dispose()
```

Addtional, I have found another discription on preceding DOC links. At section "IDisposable guidance for Transient and shared instances"

There is a more confused description:

> The instance should be disposed before the scope ends.

Comment: Given that both lifetimes are just documented as "disposed at the end of the request" I don't see anything stating any specific ordering that should be adhered to. What *actual* problem do you perceive there to be here?

Comment: I.e. at the point at which they're disposed (the end of the request), nothing should be using them anyway.

Comment: In the following description of the document, there is a sentence "The instance should be disposed before the scope ends.". So I think transient service will be disposed earlier than the scoped service but the output shown reverse order. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked example contains the following;

```cs
// snip
ExemplifyDisposableScoping(host.Services, "Scope 1");
Console.WriteLine();
// snip
static void ExemplifyDisposableScoping(IServiceProvider services, string scope)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{scope}...");

    using IServiceScope serviceScope = services.CreateScope();
    IServiceProvider provider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

    _ = provider.GetRequiredService<TransientDisposable>();
    _ = provider.GetRequiredService<ScopedDisposable>();
    _ = provider.GetRequiredService<SingletonDisposable>();
}
```

From your output;

```
Scope 1...
ScopedDisposable.Dispose()
TransientDisposable.Dispose()

Scope 2...
ScopedDisposable.Dispose()
TransientDisposable.Dispose()
```

See that blank line in the middle of the output? This should tell you that both services were disposed between the calls to `.WriteLine($"{scope}...");` and `.WriteLine();`. More specifically, they should have been disposed when `serviceScope` was disposed, before `ExemplifyDisposableScoping` returned.

A Dispose method shouldn't depend on the order of other objects being Disposed. So you shouldn't care which service is actually disposed first.

Though I believe that the default .net 5 `IServiceProvider` will dispose of objects in [reverse order](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceLookup/ServiceProviderEngineScope.cs#L86). As `TransientDisposable` was created first, it should be disposed last.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have inspected source code link mentioned by your anwser. I find the `IServiceProvider` provide the container  service management structure  like *stack*.

Answer (score -2):

```
A transient service is instantiated every time an instance is requested.
A singleton service is instantiated only once. On requests of this type, always the same instance is returned.
With scoped registrations, an instance is created within every scope where the type is requested.
```

This will help you more in learning dependency injection : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines